# I am new to flutter and dart so i have being trying to use my phone to test the demo flutter file in android studio but i keep getting this error

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
> Could not download kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.6.10/kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.6.10/kotlin-reflect-1.6.10.jar'.
> > Network is unreachable: connect
> and

each time I try to click the link I download some files I don't how to use please help me

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are properly connected to the internet and try again?

It's probably a network issue as said in the error.

> Network is unreachable

Comment: i am connected to the internet